# Make histogram diagram without imhist

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make a histogram of an image without using the imhist function. How can I replicate this without using imhist?

```
originalImage = imread('hips.png');
imhist(originalImage); title('Histogram with Matlab');
```

I know that I should create a 2D array, and go to each pixel with a 2 for loop, but I don't know what to do next.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the hist function to get the number of pixels for each frequency value. Then you need to implement the plotting part.

The code is shown below:

```
function myimhist(img)
    img = im2uint8(img);

    [count,bin] = hist(img(:), 0:255);
    stem(bin,count, 'Marker','none')

    hAx = gca;
    set(hAx, 'XLim',[0 255], 'XTickLabel',[], 'Box','on')

    %# create axes, and draw grayscale colorbar
    hAx2 = axes('Position',get(hAx,'Position'), 'HitTest','off');
    image(0:255, [0 1], repmat(linspace(0,1,256),[1 1 3]), 'Parent',hAx2)
    set(hAx2, 'XLim',[0 255], 'YLim',[0 1], 'YTick',[], 'Box','on')

    %# resize the axis to make room for the colorbar
    set(hAx, 'Units','pixels')
    p = get(hAx, 'Position');
    set(hAx, 'Position',[p(1) p(2)+26 p(3) p(4)-26])
    set(hAx, 'Units','normalized')

    %# position colorbar at bottom
    set(hAx2, 'Units','pixels')
    p = get(hAx2, 'Position');
    set(hAx2, 'Position',[p(1:3) 26])
    set(hAx2, 'Units','normalized')

    %# link x-limits of the two axes
    linkaxes([hAx;hAx2], 'x')
    set(gcf, 'CurrentAxes',hAx)
end
```